# How can I select a group of columns based on a csv input, in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have made a selection to retrieve my data, using pandas dataframe:

`X = goog_data[['SPY', 'PCTChange', 'HiLo', 'ClOp', 'Lag1', 'std_30', 'std_5', 'std_15','std_100','std_200','ret_5','Pairstd5','Pairret1','Pairret5','Pairret15','Pairret30','Pairret100','Pairret100','Pairstd15','Pairstd30','Pairstd100','Pairstd200']]`

Now this was manageable to do by hand. Now I want X to contain 5k of columns. How can I create a loop/query to say a CSV to attach all these columns? (I have all the column names in a CSV)

Regards

Comment: is goog_data a pandas DataFrame ? do you know the columns index you want to select ? you need an "indentifier" for those 5k columns.  I believe a little more context would help

Comment: Yes, it is a pandas dataframe. I have the columns in a csv. So could run like: ```for index, row in df.iterrows():```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will elaborate a solution, I'm not totally clear if is this what you want but if it is what I'm thinking the solution should be simply reading the file of columns and transform it into a list.
imagine we have as input two things, a dataframe with 5k cols and a csv file with name of cols we are interested to save in a separate csv:

DataFrame:

```
       col0      col1      col2    ...      col4997   col4998   col4999
0  0.698623  0.932956  0.359868    ...     0.829051  0.841925  0.984595
1  0.096496  0.438520  0.324643    ...     0.045311  0.960287  0.595798
2  0.255850  0.880708  0.944889    ...     0.490338  0.310711  0.002752
3  0.950205  0.322112  0.283922    ...     0.211629  0.996797  0.614626
4  0.211844  0.580730  0.323031    ...     0.465663  0.348202  0.872415
```

CSV(columns.csv) with columns I want:

```
col1,col2,col513,col4153,col4900,col5000
```

then:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
df_with5k_columns = pd.DataFrame({f"col{i}":[random.random() for _ in range(5)] for i in range(5000)})

with open("columns.csv") as columns_file:
    columns_to_select = columns_file.read().replace("\n","").split(",")
    df_selected_columns = df_with5k_columns.loc[:,columns_to_select]
    print(df_selected_columns)
```

would generate this:

```
       col1      col2    col513   col4153   col4900   col4952
0  0.037199  0.413641  0.790565  0.181794  0.678537  0.147004
1  0.218754  0.589376  0.138483  0.197163  0.567846  0.495609
2  0.971128  0.011847  0.015084  0.134676  0.459204  0.511046
3  0.490421  0.954400  0.524425  0.564901  0.223476  0.082343
4  0.377118  0.306438  0.651674  0.896337  0.130425  0.815342
```